# Uitabbarcontroller won't respond on touching on the title of the tabbar in iPhone 5

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface, touch, uitabcontroller

I'm adding a tabbarcontroller to the main view controller. If I touch the title below the image logo of the tabbar it won't respond. If I click the image of the tabbar, it gets a click and selected. This issue is only iPhone 5(4 inch screen). But it works fine in 3.5 inch device.

Please, refer the below the image, area inside red border won't respond to touch for all tabbars.

[image]

Same issue occurs in both device a.w.a simulator. I remember a post with full tabbar click access here in StackOverflow, but can't find it right now. Please suggest a solution for this.

Comment: are you using storyboard? or is their MainWindow.xib ?

Comment: @Kabira ,I'm not using storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Edit

Based on your comment

```
I added the tabbarcontroller using, tabctrl.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 548); [self.view addSubview:tabctrl.view];
```

You should also initialize the tabBar with window bounds or self.view
or try not setting the view and tabbar will set it itself

> Previous Answer

Enable FullScreen for the MainWindow in the utilities inspector
[image]

Comment: But there is no mainwindow in my project. What to do now?

Comment: how are you initializing the window then in your project ?

Comment: In the didfinishlaunching method, I added `self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControlleriPhone5" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;`

Comment: There is no MAinwidow.xib file in my project. I just add the tabbarcontroller to that viewcontroller.

Comment: In theAppdelegate.h file , I used `@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;`

Comment: okay how do you initialize tabbar controller , post that code also

Comment: I added the tabbarcontroller using, `tabctrl.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 548);
[self.view addSubview:tabctrl.view];`

Comment: `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabctrl;` in .h file.

Answer (score 1):

```
in Main View Controller

-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // I assumed that you have created yourTabBarController in View did load

    yourTabBarController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;

}
```